# Putting Abbreviations Back Together Using Regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a `String str = "U. S. ";` Using regex, how can I make `str = "U.S."`?
str is just a portion of a large String and the rest of the String is made up of sentences, so I want a regex that works only on "one-character" sentences and multiple cases (i.e. `"A. K. A. "`and `"B. C. "`). So far, I have tried using replaceAll(), but I don't know how to refer back to the characters that make up the match that was just captured so I can use them in the replacement String.

*By "one-character" sentences I mean, in the example `"U. S.` ", `"S."`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you should tag the language as well...

Comment: thanks for reminding me I completely forgot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a regex to match one abbreviation character at a time, then you can replace it using `replaceAll()` and `$1`:

```
String s1 = "Back in the U. S. S. R.";
String s2 = s1.replaceAll("([A-Z]\\.) (?=[A-Z]\\.)", "$1");
System.out.println(s2);
```

output:

```
Back in the U.S.S.R.
```

The regex:

`([A-Z]\.)` matches a single capital letter followed by a dot, as capturing group 1, which can be referred to using `$1`.

`(?=[A-Z]\.)` a space followed by a check that there is another abbreviation character following. The check for another character after the one you are matching is necessary because you don't want to replace the space following the last character in the abbreviation. For e.g. `"John lives in the U. S. A. He is a student"` should become `"John lives in the U.S.A. He is a student"`, not `"John lives in the U.S.A.He is a student"`.

It's not possible to do it using a simple `replaceAll` if you use a regex that matches variable length abbreviations e.g. `([A-Z]\. )+(?=[A-Z]\.)` because you can't refer to the individual repeats of the capturing group in your replacement string.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how that happened your code worked perfectly :)